# Can I view all time all repo commits of a user at GitHub?

Tags: github

Actually you can go `https://github.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/commits?author=USER_NAME` and get all the commits authored by `USER_NAME` on the repo `ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME`, but I want get all commits of **all repos**.

Comment: There's no way to do this in the github app right now.

Comment: @Muhammad Thanks. If you reply in form of answer I could select it.

Comment: If the user in question is yourself, you can see a list of all repositories you've contributed to in the sidebar on the right of the GitHub home page when you're signed in. Though a bit cumbersome, you could go to `https://github.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/commits?author=USER_NAME` for each repo in that list. That would be a complete listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this on Github.com right now.

Answer (score 22):

You can now do this by prepending the prefix "author:" to a username in the search box. Or modify and use this URL directly: https://github.com/search?q=author:the_username

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. I got no commits for users that are not me.

Comment: To be specific to the author's question, you can add `type=commits` to the end of the URL to go right to the commits, i.e. 
```https://github.com/search?q=author:USERNAME&type=commits```

Answer (score 0):

On enterprise github you can look at http://github.EXAMPLE.com/orgs/ORG/dashboard, and change the personal context to the ORG of interest to see everyone's activity (pushes, merges, etc.) If you don't change the context, you don't see your own activity in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

As answered from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714593/github-api-repositories-contributed-to/47564252#47564252

you can use `GraphQL` to request at least a list: [GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

```
# This first page includes an `endCursor' to be used for the next request
query { 
  viewer {
    repositoriesContributedTo(first: 100, contributionTypes: [COMMIT, ISSUE, PULL_REQUEST, REPOSITORY]) {
      pageInfo {
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "repositoriesContributedTo": {
        "pageInfo": {
          "startCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOAAFPwQ==",
          "hasNextPage": false,
          "endCursor": "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOIJAKjQ=="
        },
        "nodes": [
          {
            "nameWithOwner": "user/repo"
          },
          ...
       ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
# This is an example of getting the next page.
# Stop getting pages when `hasNextPage` is not `true`
query { 
  viewer {
    repositoriesContributedTo(first: 100, after: "Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpHOIJAKjQ==", contributionTypes: [COMMIT, ISSUE, PULL_REQUEST, REPOSITORY]) {
      pageInfo {
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        nameWithOwner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The `after` field must be replaced by the output value in the `endCursor` field from the first query.

But nevertheless, you still would have a mixed result if want to query only a user commits repositories without repositories with only user issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714593/github-api-repositories-contributed-to/47564252#comment123285323_47564252

Comment: The link no longer works. Can you provide the original query?

Comment: @coolaj86 Seems you must be logged into GitHub and grant GraphQL to access your profile.

Answer (score 0):

## A Best Effort mix of GitHub v3 and v4 APIs

I created [`how-github-am-i`](https://github.com/coolaj86/how-github-am-i) which uses a combination of the GitHub v3 API for PRs and the GitHub v4 API for recent contributions.

It requires

- GitHub Personal Access Token
- `jq`
- POSIX-ish shell (i.e. Bash)

And will spit out output like this:

```
caddyserver/caddy:
http://www.github.com/caddyserver/caddy/commits?author=coolaj86

watchexec/watchexec:
http://www.github.com/watchexec/watchexec/commits?author=coolaj86

webinstall/webi-installers:
http://www.github.com/webinstall/webi-installers/commits?author=coolaj86
```

That at least gives you a top-level view of repositories for which a PR has been closed, or you have verified commits.

It's a best-effort solution with the available tools.

## How is it done?

If you wanted to reimplement the paging yourself, here's the basic building blocks:

#### v4 Recent Contributions

```
# get the GraphQL Query without spaces
my_query="$(echo $(echo '
    query {
      viewer {
        repositoriesContributedTo(
            first: 100,
            '"${my_after:-}"'
            contributionTypes: [
                COMMIT,
                PULL_REQUEST,
                REPOSITORY
            ]
        ) {
          pageInfo {
            startCursor
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
          nodes {
            nameWithOwner
          }
        }
      }
    }
'))"

curl -fsSL -X POST https://api.github.com/graphql \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "Authorization: bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
    -d '{"query": "'"${my_query}"'"}'
```

#### v3 Closed PRs

```
# get the login name by the token
my_user="$(
    curl -fsSL https://api.github.com/user \
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
        -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" |
        jq -r .login
)"
```

```
curl -sSL --get "https://api.github.com/search/issues" \
    -H "Authorization: bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
    --data-urlencode "q=type:pr state:closed author:${my_user}" \
    --data-urlencode "per_page=100" \
    --data-urlencode "page=${my_page}"
```